# How to Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout in play framework?

Tags: java, html, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am developing a simple web application using play framework with java and i am doing

1. Login
2. Logout
3. user info page

i developed that web app but i am getting problem

**Problem** :

**After clicking of `logout` link of my web app  i am redirecting to `login` page but if user click on back button of browser then it is going back in secure page** that i don't want.

Also used `session` but on logout i am calling **controller**:

```
public static void noCache(final Response response) {

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setHeader("EXPIRES", "0"); // Proxies

    }

    public static Result logou() {
        session().clear();

        flash("success", Messages.get("youve.been.logged.out"));
        noCache(response());

        return redirect(routes.signin.page());
    }
```

**logout link:**

```
<a href="@routes.signin.logou">Logout</a>
```

but it is going back and showing user info.

actually my web application is storing cache when user click on back button it is calling cached copy that's why i called `noCache` method but still is not working

Give me some idea to solve this issue?

Comment: To answer this I would need a few clarifications: 1) To be sure, you're saying that your application is serving a cached copy of the page? 2) The `noCache` action is the one serving the page with the sensitive user information? 3) How does your login mechanism work? (i.e. in *step 1. login* you get redirected to a url that invokes the `noCache` controller method?). If not, the problem could be that  you are rendering the user info page using a login action that doesn't set the no cache headers. Without more information it's too difficult to diagnose this imo.

Comment: @Rahul kulhari, did you find the solution? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Jsp page add the code

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-        8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```